# File Storage Laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

I am trying to make the images I upload publicly accessible. I have run `php artisan storage:link`, which linked `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.
So as I have understood to save a file to folder `photo` I have to write:

```
$path = request()->file('photo')->store('public/photos');
```

And if I want to save this path:

```
$data['photo'] = 'storage/' . $path;
```

I get the path saved like `storage/public/photos/blah.jpg`

And then I can't access the image as `domain.name/storage/public/photos/blah.jpg`, because the full path turns out to be have two `public` - one from the created link and the other I state to save in the correct folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $data['photo'] = $path; and then in your view or where you want to display image just use Storage:uri($path); you'll get the image

Comment: if you want to access the image just use `src="/storage/photos/blah.jpg"`, the word public isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Store your file like this. To make file publicly available using symlink then you need to store file inside `app/public` folder or subfolder inside `app/public`.

```
request()->file('photo')->store(storage_path('app/public/photos'));
```

Now store only `photos/blah.jpg` in database and access it like this

```
domain.name/storage/photos/blah.jpg
```